# Automatic YouTube transcript alignment. How to do?

Tags: youtube, alignment, closed-captions, transcription

We have many videos on YouTube and we would like to offer automatic YouTube transcript alignment for site visitors. What we want is pretty much like [this example](http://www.3playmedia.com/how-it-works/webinars/best-practices-automatic-transcript-alignment).

But instead of word by word automatic alignment, we would like sentence by sentence alignment, such as [this example](http://ecorner.stanford.edu/authorMaterialInfo.html?mid=2396) (please click the "Show Transcript" button)

We have captions for our YouTube videos already. We want to put transcript and video side by side, exactly like the example on 3playmedia.com.

Could anyone kindly suggest me how to do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use CMUSphinx for that, see Aligner demo in the tutorial [http://cmusphinx.sourceforg.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4)

Answer (score 0):

There is a paid solution at voicebase.com which even does PCI - Compliance and redaction (http://voicebase.readthedocs.io/en/v2-beta/how-to-guides/pci-ssn-pii-detection.html)

I have not tried it yet but looks very promising.